# Euclid Book 1 Proposition 4

Tags: euclidean-geometry

In Euclid's *The Elements*, Book 1, Proposition 4, he makes the assumption that one can create an angle between two lines and then construct the same angle from two different lines.  I do not see anywhere in the list of definitions, common notions, or postulates that allows for this assumption.  When teaching my students this, I do teach them congruent angle construction (with straight edge and compass), but do not understand why Euclid is allowed to make this logical leap.  Thanks for any help you can give.

Comment: This question doesn't belong on Mathoverflow, but might get a good reception on matheducators.stackexchange.com

Comment: Posted on MESE [here](https://matheducators.stackexchange.com/q/17799/511).